# Changing the value type/value of a cell in DataGridView c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

I am populating the DataGridView through `DataGridView.DataSource` where the source is an SQL Server database table. The database table however has columns of different types. Although most of the data in the table is of type `INT` or `VARCHAR`, there are a few `BIT` and `IMAGE` type columns.

The problem I have has to do with what gets automatically shown in the DataGridView. Although the data in most columns get converted to `Strings` and is shown as such, the `BIT` and `IMAGE` type columns do not. The `IMAGE` type columns show the image (this is fine with me, I want it to do this) while the `BIT` type columns show CheckBoxes (**I don't want this**, I want the data to be shown as a `String`).

I wish to do some formatting after loading the data and change the cells that have CheckBoxes to cells that have `Strings`. However I don't seem to find a way to do it.

I have tried changing the value through the following: (Please note that prior to the code below being called, `cell` has previously been filtered as a CheckBox cell.)

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(cell.Value))
{
    cell.Value = "Yes";
}
else
{
    cell.Value = "No";
}
```

I have also attempted to change the cell type prior to changing its value as shown below.

```
String dummyString;
if (Convert.ToBoolean(cell.Value))
{
    dummyString = "Yes";
}
else
{
    dummyString = "No";
}
cell.ValueType = typeof(String);
cell.Value = dummyString;
```

Unfortunately this has also failed to produce the results I desire. Both attempts don't do anything to the DataGridView that I can see and still display CheckBoxes in the cells instead of Strings.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can't you add your columns first (using the designer or code) and set `AutgenerateColumns = false` and then set `theDataSource`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a new cell of the type I wanted, and replacing the old cell with the new cell. Please see below:

```
String dummyString;
if (Convert.ToBoolean(cell.Value))
{
    dummyString = "Yes";
}
else
{
    dummyString = "No";
}
int rowIndex = cell.RowIndex;
int colIndex = cell.ColumnIndex;

dataGridView1[colIndex, rowIndex] = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
dataGridView1[colIndex, rowIndex].Value = dummyString;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could Populate an intermediate Dataset with the infor coming from DataBase and then copy that information to a new dataset wich is the source for the datagrid.
In the process of copying that information you can do what you need.